# What is called defer-node-expansion in XML?

Tags: java, xml, apache, parsing

What this feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/defer-node-expansion" does?

i have read about this [feature](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/features.html). But was really unable to understand what will happen if this is set to false.

Can anyone come up elaborately on this as i don't find any other link that explain to the ability i understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a form **[lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)**: DOM nodes are created as you traverse tree.

This is a common design pattern, it is widely used. For example Hibernate calls it [Lazy Fetching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html).

Answer (score 3):

by deferred node expansion, basically, a lot of objects/strings are not created/allocated until you navigate to the corresponding node position... it makes dom parsing a bit faster but  tree traversal slower ...

the initial memory consumption is lower than a full-expanded DOM tree, but after traversal, the memory usage could easily be a lot higher than a full-expanded DOM tree... beware of the catch